# HDD changes between 100% and 0% with pauzes

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have a 5 year old Windows 7 laptop that is slow because of this:
The graph of the disk usage over time of the HDD looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv3D0.png).
It constantly changes between 100% and 0%: 100%, 0%, 100%, 0%...
I installed a fresh Windows 7 OS, no other programma's are running and the laptop is idling for more than 30 minutes after start up.
I can't find a website that explains this behavior.
My HDD is probably worn and this problem could probably be solved by replacing it with an SSD like the Kingston A400, but I would like to know the reason for this behavior.

Comment: Open the resource monitor in windows 7 and look at "processes with disk activity". This way you can find out what is causing the activity and how much it is. This is the first step to solve the mystery. If I would have to fire a wild guess I'd say it's either an indexing or an AV thing.

Comment: Thanks @kruemi for your help. I found that MsMpEng.exe is above in the list. It's part of Windows Defender. [Screenshot](https://we.tl/t-so4injOs7e) But when I stop this proces, the same behavior is still present...

Comment: Than the search continues. I might be that windows automatically restarts defender. Or it might be another activity.
there is also the possibility, that your harddisk is starting to fail and windows tries to access the data and the disk take a lot of time to load it. You might want to check the SMART data of your disk.